# вывод заголовка h2...h6

Tags: php, html

Известно, что через `$this->get_title` можно вывести заголовок записи, благодаря чему в плагинах есть возможность вывести `h1 title`, если применить переменные `%title%`, но я хочу вывести `h2-h6`, даже попробовал редактировать их код:

```
$this->register_replacement(
        'title h2',
        [
            'name'        => esc_html__( 'Post Title h2', 'rank-math' ),
            'description' => esc_html__( 'Title of the current post/page', 'rank-math' ),
            'variable'    => 'title h2',
            'example'     => $this->get_title('h2'),
            'nocache'     => true,
        ],
        [ $this, 'get_title' ]
        


    );
```

естественно, ничего не вышло, кроме ошибок.

Моя просьба не в том, как исправить код плагина, этот вопрос к плагину.
Я просто не могу понять, если `get_the_title()` выводит заголовок записи и отсюда соответственно `$this->get_title` выводит `h1`, тогда что выводит `h2….h6`? Например, попробовал `get_the_title(h2)`, вылезла ошибка.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: о каком плагине вообще речь?

Comment: Плагин rank math seo но дело не в плагине, а в том, что вывести текст h2...h6 из записи в качестве excerpt если я найду функцию вывода, например excerpt = h6 то плагин сам поймёт, что нужно вводить h6
Или по другому, создать отдельные переменные для h6, например %h6%

Comment: Так, дело как раз-таки в плагине. В примере из вопроса не стандартный php, тут есть какие-то функции, вызов методов. Больше подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: я подробно о проблеме написал здесь, но никто не сможет ответить https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/функция-вывода-текста-из-h2-h6-из-статьи/#post-12227523